# Binary files were found. Please don't commit binary files into SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have tried to commit some new dlls in the bin folder of my application using tortoise svn. But it throws the below error while committing.

```
svn: E165001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E165001: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
Binary files were found. Please don't commit binary files into SVN..!!
```

How to prevent this error and commit the new dlls in bin folder?

Comment: Your environment has a hook blocking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you read the error message? It says:

> Binary files were found. Please don't commit binary files into SVN..!!

It means that your administrator has configured a [hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks) that prevents you from committing and importing certain types of files (based on their extension or MIME type, maybe). You can't (and you should not) get rid of this error yourself. Contact your admin or manager and he'll explain you what you are doing wrong.